# Cant seem to compare JSON results in Android

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON array of matches:

```
{
    "matches": [{
        "match": {
            "player1_id": 35161770,
            "player2_id": 35161786,
            "winner_id": 35161770,
            "loser_id": 35161786,
        }
    }, {
        "match": {
            "player1_id": 35161812,
            "player2_id": 35161778,
            "winner_id": 35161812,
            "loser_id": 35161778,
        }
    }, {
        "match": {
            "player1_id": 35161770,
            "player2_id": 35161775,
            "winner_id": 35161775,
            "loser_id": 35161770,
        }
    }]
}
```

I am iterating through this array as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matches.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject object = matches.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject match = object.getJSONObject("match");

    if (match.get("winner_id") == match.get("player1_id"))
    {
        Log.d("result", "one");
    }
    else if (match.get("winner_id") == match.get("player2_id"))
    {
        Log.d("result", "two");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("result", "tie");
    }
}
```

However, no matter what I do, the result always shows up as a `tie`...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using gson instead of JSONObject?

Comment: it can be because you use `==` insead of `.equals()`.Try `match.get("winner_id").equals(match.get("player2_id"))`

Comment: also, what is the value of `matches`? because in the structure, you have
`[ { ... } ]` , you might be thinking that you have `[ ... ]` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONObject.get("")` will return an `Object`. You can change it to:

```
match.getString("winner_id").equals(match.getString("player1_id"))
```

As @gj_ point out, you can also use the following:

```
match.getInt("winner_id") == match.getInd("player1_id")
```

Comment: @gj_: yep, that'll do

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
JSONObject object = matches.optJSONObject(i);
```